# How to add smooth scrolling to all in page anchor links

Tags: javascript

Trying to write a script to add smooth scrolling for all links that resolve to an anchor on the current page. Trying to make this generic so it works site-wide.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a')
var anchorLinks = []

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i += 1) {
  console.log(links[i].href, window.location.href)
}
```

That's my start, but I'm running into challenges, and I'm reaching out on Stackoverflow to see if anyone's done this without jQuery.

I have to check if the href has a `#`, but I also have to check if the current URL matches the href, because other sites use `#`'s too.

Would that do it? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: That should work, and you can always use a regular expression to do it in one line. Otherwise, make sure you add `toLowerCase()` to both the link href and page href when checking if your website has case insensitive paths

Comment: I found [this pen](https://codepen.io/rleve/pen/iCbgy) and modified it a bit to be more generic. I don't think this takes care of all your requirements but here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kr71730y/2/) anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up, see [Location object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

Try this:

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll('a')
var anchorLinks = [].filter.call(links,a=>(
  a.host==window.location.host&&
  a.pathname==window.location.pathname&&
  a.search==window.location.search&&
  a.hash!=window.location.hash))
```

There is actually another way to do that:

```
var locwohash = window.location.href.replace(/#.+/, "")
var anchorLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="'+locwohash+'"],a[href^="#"]')
```

Should be faster, but will be complex if wanting to be robust to different types of link hrefs. (for `http://example.com/path/to/page#hash`, there are many hrefs to link to anchor in this page, `#another-hash`, `page#another-hash`, `example.com/path/to/page#another-hash`, `/path/to/page#another-hash`, `//example.com/path/to/page#another-hash`, `http://example.com/path/to/page#another-hash`, all of these are equivalent but not identical by selector.